# Coding to an interface on a Spring Controller method with @RequestMapping

Tags: spring, controller

I have a Controller with the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST)
public ModelAndView emailRegister(EmailParameter parameters, ModelMap model) {}
```

Where EmailParameter is an interface. I understand Spring (magically?) maps the incoming HTTP parameters to my object fields by name, and it can't do this as I have declared an Interface.

Is it possible to declare an interface here, if so is there additional config I need somewhere?

I don't have extensive programming experience so I may be wrong in trying to use an Interface type here, but I believe this is what I should be doing?

Additionally if someone could explain how Spring maps the request parameters to my object fields, that would be much appreciated. Or a link to where this is explained, as I haven't been able to find one!

Thanks

Comment: Why an interface in this context? Use a bean class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use Interface because Spring needs to instantiate that object, otherwise you will be requiring the property editors OR converters.

Read the following post to know about How Spring MVC Binds Parameter?

Read section "Binding Domain Object" in following link.

https://web.archive.org/web/20160516151809/http://www.jpalace.org/document/92/binding-and-validation-of-handler-parameters-in-spring-mvc-controllers